# yum + dependencies errors

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, dependencies, openldap

during yum installation , we get the following dependencies errors

```
Error: Package: openldap-2.4.40-8.el7.i686 (@local)
           Requires: libplds4.so
           Removing: nspr-4.10.8-2.el7_1.i686 (@local)
               libplds4.so
           Updated By: nspr-4.19.0-1.el7_5.x86_64 (/nspr-4.19.0-1.el7_5.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: openldap-2.4.40-8.el7.i686 (@local)
           Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.11)
           Removing: nss-3.19.1-18.el7.i686 (@local)
               libnss3.so(NSS_3.11)
           Updated By: nss-3.36.0-7.el7_5.x86_64 (/nss-3.36.0-7.el7_5.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: openldap-2.4.40-8.el7.i686 (@local)
           Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.2)
           Removing: nss-3.19.1-18.el7.i686 (@local)
               libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.2)
           Updated By: nss-3.36.0-7.el7_5.x86_64 (/nss-3.36.0-7.el7_5.x86_64)
               Not found
```

we see that Requires: **libplds4.so**

how we can find which rpm that represented by - Requires: l**ibnss3.so**(NSS_3.11)

Comment: Could you please elaborate: what command did you run? Which repo's are in use? yum config file?

Comment: note the **i686** in addition to **x86_64**.  Assuming your rhel/centos installed as X86_64 then you probably don't wan't any i686 stuff, and vice-versa.  An `rpm -qa` will let you know if everything is x86-64 or i686.  I had a similar problem with RHEL and was caused by doing some optional software from nux which caused an i686 to get installed and that ended up causing conflicts down the road for me- solution was to backtrack and remove i686 stuff until YUM was happy; and it was in fact a problem with *nss*

Comment: my RHEL or Centos systems are all x86_64, fully functional with YUM happy, and I have zero i686 rpm's present.  Be mindful when you start getting a mix of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid repository server, the most common one to get the name of rpm name for a file is

```
# yum whatprovides */libplds4.so
```